# Amadeus Master Pricer Travel Board - search by carrier?

Tags: amadeus

I would like to specify the carrier when sending queries to Master Pricer Travel Board. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, which API do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your XML request:

```
<travelFlightInfo>
    <companyIdentity>
        <carrierQualifier>M</carrierQualifier>
        <carrierId>BA</carrierId>
    </companyIdentity>
</travelFlightInfo>
```

carrierQualifier with value M means only the following airlines are allowed.
carrierId is the airline IATA code